# to have KeyDown event in C or C++ (mac OSX)

Tags: c++, c, macos

I know that it is possible to have KeyDown event in Objective-c but I don't know about that language but I would like to control my program with keyboard,which is in C and C++.
I found some examples but all of them are for windows or java...
I search xcode it seems that everything is about Objective-c and cocoa that I don't know about them, I just looking for simple example ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this for a GUI app or a console app?

Comment: GUI on OS X has mostly, if not exclusively, Objective-C APIs. If you know C and C++, you will be able to copy an Objective-C based example into your code and run it.

Comment: I started trying SDL ... I just runed it, I should read more I guess...

Comment: If your application can be linked with ApplicationServices framework then you should be able to use Quartz event handling calls.[Quartz event reference documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot , I used SDL_KeyDown and it worked great for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is Carbon Events Manager.

Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003081-CH1-SUBSECTION9) article to see an example of how to use it.
You would have to install an event handler for { kEventClassKeyboard, kEventRawKeyDown }.